# aioschedule запуск задания в определенный день

Tags: python, aiogram, aioschedule

у меня есть телеграмм бот, в нем я использую aioschedule
мне нужно, чтобы задание запустилось только один раз в определенный день
например:

```
aioschedule.once(datetime.datetime(year=2022, month=2, day=15, hour=9, minute=45), func)
```

у синхронного schedule есть функция once, а у aioschedule только every.
Получается самой библиотекой не предусмотрен данный функционал?
Единственный выход, который я вижу, это в самой функции прописать проверку, что наступил нужный день и тогда сделать определенные действия, а само задание запускать каждый день, но это выглядит не очень красиво.

Comment: В schedule не нахожу никакой функции once. В документации schedule показан способ одноразового запуска через отмену после первого запуска: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#run-a-job-once Аналогично будет работать и в aioschedule